# Why SpriteKit Show threat in app delegate class when run the app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

When I add elements from one array to another then remove all the elements from the first one ---> Xcode makes crash(open AppDelegate class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any attempt to access a non-existent element in an array causes a crash. I believe this is because Arrays are optimised, highly, as is accessing them, for performance. There's little safety.

Without some of your code I'm only guessing, but this sounds like you're attempting to access a part of your array that no longer exists.

Comment: Acctually what I want to do is to make an array that update its elements (just has new elements) and an array that save all elements (the new elements which added in the first one and the removed elements which removed when new elements added to the first array)